# Android drawer ListView doesn't show item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have created an Android app and want to show a drawer on top left. The drawer is shown there but the list items doesn't show when I click on the drawer. Below is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.yihanwang.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/homepage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="HikingMate"
            android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
            android:textSize="100px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/topTextView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/topTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topTextView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Hikers best friend"
            android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
            android:textSize="50px" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:elegantTextHeight="true"
            android:text="Plants  near  me"
            android:textColor="#0C640F"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Below is my `drawer_list_item.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

Below is my `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private TextView topText;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Title");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Title");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent subscription = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(subscription);

            }
        });

        topText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topTextView);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my string resource for the listview item array:

```
<string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
```

**EDIT1**

I override below function:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and remove this line: `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`.

Now when I click on the toggle the list-view-items are shown but the toggle icon is not changed. Below is the screen shot:

[android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTibe.png)

You can see from above screenshot that the toggle button on the top-left is black icon but what I set is a white icon. I set it by `mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);` and it seems that this line doesn't work if I remove: `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`

Comment: Thank you for you help, I changed the textColor to #000, but it does not show up

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and the listview items are shown. But once I remove `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` the toggle button becomes the default icon. How can I set the icon if I remove this line?

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you post your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Actually, the answer here would be exactly the same, so I should mark it as a duplicate instead. Thanks, though. Glad it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this;

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.yihanwang.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/homepage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="HikingMate"
        android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
        android:textSize="100px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/topTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/topTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topTextView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Hikers best friend"
        android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
        android:textSize="50px" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mapButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:text="Plants  near  me"
        android:textColor="#0C640F"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I changed my codes as you said, but items are not shown up, and the background is while.